# django 1.10 list of installed apps

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-1.10

So I'm trying this:

```
import my_project.settings
DEVOPS_APPS = [ app for app in my_project.settings.INSTALLED_APPS if not "django" in app ]
```

Sometimes when I refresh, the data doesn't show.

Other times when I refresh, the data shows.

Still some other times when I refresh, I get the full list of `INSTALLED_APPS`

My index function looks like so:

```
template = loader.get_template('dashboard/index.html')
      context = {
        'title': "Telematics DevOps Automation Team",
        'installed_apps': DEVOPS_APPS,
        'server': 'atllvasbap001i.hughestelematics.net',
        'charts': data['charts']
        }
return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the relationship between those two snippets? Where are you using DEVOPS_APPS?

Comment: Woops. I'm using DEVOPS_APPS in the context dict. Edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using settings, django recommends  importing `django.conf.settings` instead of importing your settings module:

```
from django.conf import settings
[app for app in settings.INSTALLED_APPS if not 'django' in app]
# will output
# >>> [u'user_auth', u'payment', u'logistic', u'art', u'home', 
#      u'swipe', u'easy_thumbnails', u'crispy_forms', u'floppyforms',   
#      u'rest_framework', u'rest_framework.authtoken', 
#      u'adminsortable']
```

A recommended read on this is [Using settings in Python code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#using-settings-in-python-code).